# Many-to-many bi-directional mapping

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to mapping many to many bidirectional. I have created two entity classes (Book, Author). Tables are created but in the Joint table data is not inserting here you can see my screenshots below.
I think I have written everything right but I am not sure what is wrong in my project. Please correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried to set the author for the book as well? eg.: b1.getAuthors.add(a1);b2.getAuthors.add(a1);

Comment: I have already set but I commented once I uncommented it it's working that was a silly mistake I have realized it. But thank you for your question.

Answer (score 1):

With a bidirectional association you are supposed to update the association on both sides, usually with an helper method. See: [Hibernate user guide - bidirectional many-to-many](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional):

```
@Entity
class Book {
   ...
   public void addAuthor(Author author) {
      authors.add(author);
      author.getBooks().add(this);
   }
   ...
}
```

Now you can change your code to something similar to:

```
Author a1 = ...
Authort a2 = ..

Book b1 = ...
b1.addAuthor(a1);
b1.addAuthor(a2);

save(b1);
```